# Output of dmesg | grep ath10k shows lot of errors (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, drivers

My Wifi is really slow in Ubuntu 20.04. My driver is ath10k_pci as per `lshw -C network`:

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 32
       serial: 5c:3a:45:12:ad:7f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.11.0-37-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00140-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.1.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:138 memory:93000000-931fffff
```

Whenever I run `$ dmesg | grep ath10k` I see the same error reported repeatedly, several times each second:

```
invalid ht params rate 1440 100kbps nss 2 mcs 7
```

Does anyone know any fix?

Comment: Did you solve this? I see the same issue with Fedora 38: `kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: invalid vht params rate 1730 100kbps nss 2 mcs 9`. Same error with rate 1920.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://lore.kernel.org/ath10k/5c31f6dadbcc3dcb19239ad2b6106773@codeaurora.org/) the problem is caused by buggy firmware. Please try updating your firmware to the latest [release](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/ath10k) and see if it helps.

Comment: I already have the same firmware.

Comment: How do you know? Please git clone this repo and overwrite the existing files.

Comment: I see the same issue with Fedora 38: `kernel: ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: invalid vht params rate 1730 100kbps nss 2 mcs 9`